# ASP.NET server side validation not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

In My Application server side validation function is not working.even function is not called. i have put debugger on thuat function but it is not stopped ny debugger .i.e. function is not called

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" ID="txtMobilePhone" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CausesValidation="true"/>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvMobilePhone" runat="server" OnServerValidate="cvMobilePhone_ServerValidate" 
                            Text="Mobile Phone already exist in this Reward Program." ErrorMessage="Mobile Phone already exist in this Reward Program."
                            Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vgStep2" ControlToValidate="txtMobilePhone" CssClass="error"></asp:CustomValidator>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMobilePhone" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobilePhone"
                            ErrorMessage="Mobile Phone is required." CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="vgStep2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvMobilePerVal" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validateEmailOrMobilePerVal"
                            Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vgStep2"></asp:CustomValidator>


 <asp:Button ID="btnStep2Upper" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnSaveContactClick" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="vgStep2" vg="vgStep2" OnClientClick="return ClientValidate();" />
```

**Server Side Code**

```
    protected void cvMobilePhone_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs value)
        {  /* I have put debugger here but control is not coming here*/
            /* my validation logic*/
protected void cvMobilePhone_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs value)
    {
        if (txtMobilePhone.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            RewardProgramDataContext db = new RewardProgramDataContext();
            Boolean f = false;
            string MobilePhone = cmnFunc.RemoveMobilePhoneFormat(txtMobilePhone.Text.Trim());
            if (Request["id"] != null)
            {
                var cData = db.spContactSelectAllSingle(new Guid(Request["id"])).SingleOrDefault();
                if (cData != null)
                {
                    if (cmnFunc.RemoveMobilePhoneFormat(cData.MobilePhone) == MobilePhone)
                    {
                        f = true;
                        value.IsValid = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (f == false)
            {
                var res = db.spContactDuplicateMobile(new Guid(ddlContactList.SelectedValue), MobilePhone).SingleOrDefault();
                if (res.Column1 <= 0)
                {
                    value.IsValid = true;
                    customIsValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    value.IsValid = false;
                    customIsValid = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

now when i click submit button all clent side validation working but serside custom validator is not calling

Comment: Have you try to remove `OnClientClick` part in your button? Can you post the code in your `cvMobilePhone_ServerValidate` method?

Comment: @Iswanto San: my server side validation function is not even executing. it is not event called. i don't know why it is not firing.

Comment: Is your `ClientValidate()` return true or false?

Comment: it is returning true.my cursor reached directly to button click event.Not stopped on server side validaor function  i have used page.validate() and Page.IsValid. but it is returning true.even though button event should not be called, it is called

Answer (score 0):

You forget to set the `ControlToValidate` property?

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvMobilePhone" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobilePhone" OnServerValidate="cvMobilePhone_ServerValidate" 
                            Text="Mobile Phone already exist in this Reward Program." ErrorMessage="Mobile Phone already exist in this Reward Program."
                            Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vgStep2" CssClass="error"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: sorry i made mistake in copy paste. but it is there in my code i have put ControlToValidate.

Comment: you don't need the property `ControlToValidate` on a `CustomValidator` as all the logic is in the `ServerValidate`-eventHandler, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate(v=vs.110).aspx: `This property must be set to the ID of an input control for all validation controls except the CustomValidator control, which can be left blank.`

Answer (score 0):

You have a combination of two different things causing this behaviour.

Firstly, note that although—as has been said by others—you do not have to specify `ControlToValidate`, doing so restricts the circumstances in which the server-side custom validation event will fire. Specifically, if you leave it unset, the event always fires on postback, whereas if you set it, the event only fires *when the control identified by `ControlToValidate` has a non-empty value*.

Secondly, by specifying OnClientClick, you are telling the framework that you will take care of client-side validation, which will now not fire unless you call it from your OnClientClick function. Although you have not included your `ClientValidate` function in your question, I suspect you are not doing so, which leaves your `RequiredFieldValidator` powerless to prevent the postback.

In combination, these two things mean that

- the postback occurs *despite* the empty textbox, and
- the server-side custom validation does not fire on postback, *because of* the empty textbox.

You can call the client validation from your custom function using `Page_ClientValidate())`, which will be present in your page script since the page contains validators.

```
function ClientValidate() {
    if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
        //do custom validation, maybe return false 
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: one weird thing i found that it is not working on some machine but same code working on other machine....

Comment: could be javascript disabled in a browser

Comment: nope i have tested. JavaScript is enable.... actually it is working on my all local machine but not working on live serve machine....

Comment: what's working? Your original code? Or what I suggested.

Comment: my original code is working.(without controlToValidate)

Comment: It would be easier to assist if you could provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As for not working on live machine, that seems clearly a different problem, as you now have it working in the debugger which was your question here.